# Efecto de slide up de panel uber, con css y jquery

Tags: css3, phonegap, jquery-mobile

Estoy desarrollando una app con phonegap y jquery mobile. Tengo una pantalla similar a la pantalla del mapa de uber. Uber tiene en la pantalla del mapa un panel de pie el cual al darle touch y subir el panel sube. ¿Cómo se llama o cómo podría hacer ese efecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas Wilmer, esto que comentas se puede hacer con [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap). Sólo tienes que adquirir la librería (que és gratuita) y usar las clases en [html](/questions/tagged/html) para crear los efectos, és una librería muy completa, te servirá para ésto.

Aparte del código te dejo un link que te ayudará a usar esta librería.
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

Tu código sería algo como:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>The .dropup class makes the dropdown menu expand upwards instead of downwards:</p>
  <div class="dropup">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropup Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Si quieres el código en [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) te lo dejo aquí abajo:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").slideUp();
});
```

Explicación detallada : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slideup.asp

Comment: ok gracias. Pruebo y le aviso